# RestSharp POST request - Body x-www-form-urlencoded values

Tags: c#, rest, post, restsharp

I'm trying to convert some API tests that were done using POSTMAN.
The problem I'm facing is to do a POST request to get a token + `refreshToken`.

** OBS: I'm pretty sure I'm using the same `client_id` + `client_secret` that I use in Postman.

**Body - POSTMAN**
[image: Body]

**Headers:**
[image]

My code so far:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;

private (string,string) GetAccessToken_RefreshToken() //(string, string)
        {

            var request = new RestRequest(URL_TOKEN, Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic dndmci1hcGktY2xpZW50Og==");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            // Request Body as x-www-form-urlencoded
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password",ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("username", "SALESPERSON1",ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            // request.AddParameter("X-IBM-Client-Id:", "6cc43ffd-9818-43d4-b1d5-4d87fa5258de");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "vwfr-trusted-api-client",ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", "5876d4ff-6434-40ce-9635-cf3920b240d1",ParameterType.GetOrPost);

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                accessToken = (string)jsonObject["access_token"];
                refreshToken = (string)jsonObject["refresh_token"];
                Console.WriteLine($"Token: {AccessToken}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Refresh_token: {RefreshToken} " + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get access token. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
            return (accessToken, refreshToken);
        }
```

RESPONSE:

> RestSharp.RestResponse
> {"httpCode":"401","httpMessage":"Unauthorized","moreInformation":"Invalid client id or secret."}

NEW Implementation

```
private (string, string) GetAccessToken_RefreshToken()
        {

            var request = new RestRequest(URL_TOKEN, Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic dndmci1hcGktY2xpZW50Og==");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "SALESPERSON1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "vwfr-trusted-api-client"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "5876d4ff-6434-40ce-9635-cf3920b240d1")
            };

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var encodedValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parameter.Value);
                request.AddParameter(parameter.Key, encodedValue, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            }

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                accessToken = (string)jsonObject["access_token"];
                refreshToken = (string)jsonObject["refresh_token"];
                Console.WriteLine($"Token: {AccessToken}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Refresh_token: {RefreshToken} " + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get access token. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
            return (accessToken, refreshToken);
        }
```

Comment: For urlencoding, you have to create a key/value pair listing <string, string>, and then encode it instead of adding them as parameters. Also, your media type has to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and passed in as string content: ie (new StringContent(myString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: The code actually looks correct except you don't need to set the content type manually, it's a default POST request content type anyway. I would check the actual request body by calling a request bin https://pipedream.com/requestbin to ensure there's no mismatch. It always quite obvious what went wrong when you inspect the actual call.

Comment: Hi @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩, It's not working at all, any idea why? I'll add the new code to the question.